# Why do I get "libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT" when running a IOIO Mint application?

Tags: java, android, ioio

I'm trying to make a simple application, which runs on an Android device (*Alcatel One Touch 4030D*, Android 4.1.1) and reads data from analog input pins of [IOIO Mint](http://www.adafruit.com/products/885) via BlueTooth.

I'm getting the error given below. What does it mean and how can I fix it?

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/mtprof/status: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:451)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:105)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord.mtProf(ActivityRecord.java:987)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord.windowsDrawn(ActivityRecord.java:775)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord$Token.windowsDrawn(ActivityRecord.java:266)
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage(WindowManagerService.java:7523)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$WMThread.run(WindowManagerService.java:911)
Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:435)
        ... 9 more
```

**Update 1 (11.06.2013 00:40 MSK):** Migrating the application from API level 10 to API level 15 didn't help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620641/android-error-open-failed-enoent

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here, but it seems you are trying to open the *status* file located in the */proc/mtprof* directory. The error indicates that there isn't a file named *status* at that location, so try running a search for the *status* file that you are trying to open. Then you should be able to correct the file location in your program.