# Error when trying to Debug Android app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-debug

Please help.!! I'm getting the error posted in the image when i try to debug my app, it was working fine and now i cant find the problem.. Any suggestion??

The app stucks in waiting for device for debugging. but it works fine if i run the app in release mode..

My app is developed in Android Studio latest version and using Api 19﻿.
How do i clean my project? i've already tried this:

```
gradlew clean
gradlew compile
```

[image: Error while debugging]

Please somebody help!!

Answer (score 0):

There's none of your source code attached so i can't tell for sure but it could be because you're trying to write data to the root of internal storage. If that's the case you just need to change where you're writing your data.

Source : [Android Error - Open Failed ENOENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620641/android-error-open-failed-enoent)

I wouldn't know for sure though since i can't see your code.

Comment: thank you for your answer! but i'm not writing anything to the root of internal storage. I dont know what part of my code post here because it was working very well, it just started to do this

Comment: Do you have a method called "access"? If so you might want to post it's code. Otherwise i don't know how i can try to help further