# android FileWriter cannot open file ( file not found)

Tags: android, java-io

I am trying to write a fake csv file , but I always get an IOException : file not found
my code seems correct, but I may have missed something somewhere ...
exception is raised on the filewriter = new FileWriter line

```
java.io.File file;
file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), "/swimmer/trainings/");
String mTrainingsPath = file.getPath();

String csvFilePath = mTrainingsPath + java.io.File.separator + training.filename;    
file = new File( csvFilePath);

 try {
 FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter( file );
 PrintWriter csvOut = new PrintWriter( fileWriter );

String data = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\\n" 
+ " Cras facilisis elit eu nisl laoreet mollis.\\n" 
+ " In feugiat nec elit at tincidunt.";

csvOut.println( data );
csvOut.close();

} catch( IOException e ) {
Log.e(TAG, "IOException in creating csv file");
Log.e(TAG, "STACKTRACE");
Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
 }
```

here is the log file :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.swimtechtest.swimmer/files/swimmer/trainings/myFirstTraining.csv: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:42)
at ...swimmer.database.DatabaseHandler.putFakeTraining(DatabaseHandler.java:86
```

directory /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.swimtechtest.swimmer/files/swimmer/trainings/ exists (created previously)

Comment: Check that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620641/android-error-open-failed-enoent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your directories. Given your current local variable named `file`, call `file.mkdirs()` to create them. This will not throw an error if the directories already exist, so usually you just call `mkdirs()` before attempting to use the directory. Or, use `exists()` to see if it is there, then call `mkdirs()` if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.. I was 100% sure that the directory existed , as I check it in my app before adding 'standard' trainings files.... BUT in this case , I create this fake training directly when my app starts ( customer feature request added later ..)  so in this case .. the directory doesn't exist !   better checking 7 times ...