# Android unable to save image file to SD card

Tags: android, image, save

I'm using OpenGL to draw frame in Android phone and I want to save the image to the storage, but I get error: the directory is not found and no such file directory, I do put permission in the Android Manifest like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.etoff.appsopengl">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name="com.etoff.appsopengl.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

this is my coding in stage class:

```
if(SC==true){
            int screenshotSize = screenWidth * screenHeight;
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(screenshotSize * 4);
            bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            gl.glReadPixels(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bb);
            int pixelsBuffer[] = new int[screenshotSize];
            bb.asIntBuffer().get(pixelsBuffer);
            bb = null;
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            bitmap.setPixels(pixelsBuffer, screenshotSize-screenWidth, -screenWidth, 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
            pixelsBuffer = null;
            short sBuffer[] = new short[screenshotSize];
            ShortBuffer sb = ShortBuffer.wrap(sBuffer);
            bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(sb);
            for (int i = 0; i < screenshotSize; ++i) {
                short v = sBuffer[i];
                sBuffer[i] = (short) (((v&0x1f) << 11) | (v&0x7e0) | ((v&0xf800) >> 11));
            }
            sb.rewind();
            bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(sb);
            screen = bitmap;

            String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/OpenGL";
            File dir = new File(file_path);
            if(!dir.exists()){
                dir.mkdirs();
            }
            String format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss", java.util.Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
            File file = new File(file_path, format + ".png");
            OutputStream fOut;
            try {
                fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                screen.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            SC = false;
        }
```

this is the error I get in the console:

```
W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/OpenGL/20151001152329.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
W/System.err﹕ at com.etoff.appsopengl.Stage$MyRenderer.onDrawFrame(Stage.java:167)
W/System.err﹕ at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1531)
W/System.err﹕ at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
W/System.err﹕ ... 5 more
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11620848/3593066

Comment: I do create  folder where I write the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error:**

> Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such
>   file or directory) at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)

basically your image file is not found because file path you have given is wrong.

Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get Path of SD Card.

Remove the `.getAbsolutePath()` and it will be fine. `Environment.getExternalStoreDirectory()` will give you the path to wherever the manufacture has set their external storage.

Try

```
String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/OpenGL"
```

instead of

```
String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/OpenGL";
```

**EDIT1:**

You need to add this permission to write file into Internal storage.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I recommend you to save image in Internal Storage rather that SD card because Different manufacturer use different SD card name so there is different SD card path for different devices.

**EDIT2:**

Try this code

```
 String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/OpenGL";
 File dir = new File(file_path);
 if(!dir.exists()){
     dir.mkdirs();
 }
 String format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss", java.util.Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
 File file = new File(file_path, format + ".png");
```

instead of

```
String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/OpenGL";
File dir = new File(file_path);
if(!dir.exists()){
    dir.mkdirs();
}
String format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss", java.util.Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
File file = new File(dir, format + ".png");
```

**EDIT3:**
give both permission in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and also try to use both `dir.mkdir();` and `dir.mkdirs();`
 with above 2 permissions.

Comment: Ok Sir I try use internal storage

Comment: String file_path = Environment.getDataDirectory().toString() + "/OpenGL"; I updated my code but I still have the same error

Comment: do you have added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" /> pemission ?and pls post updated code in your question

Comment: also try this OutputStream  fOut = new FileOutputStream(file); instead of  FileOutputStream  fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

Comment: use File file = new File(file_path, format + ".png"); instead File file = new File(dir, format + ".png");

Comment: you have not updated your code . i can find you are using String file_path = Environment.getDataDirectory().toString() + "/OpenGL"; instead of String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/OpenGL"

Comment: No sir, I using Environment.getDataDirectory().toString()

Comment: use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/OpenGL" there

Comment: Ya used, after change android Manifest to external storage, now error still same

Comment: pls post your all updated code you are using till now

Comment: Ok done, I have updated all now and tested, the error still same

Comment: why you have not given this permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />?

Comment: because you are asking me to use external? Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()  return internal storage path not SD card path

Comment: Ok, I have updated again and tried, the error still same

Comment: Sir, what is the main problem with my coding?

Comment: I have given solutions which i have known these solutions should have to work

Comment: I dunno why the directory and PNG file is not written in the storage?

Comment: It's worked, but the saved image only save my rendered texture but it's ignored the background... I dunno why?

Comment: there might be some issue while creating bitmap

Comment: Probably in onDraweFrame I did't draw the background I think I need study again, anyway thanks Bro

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method to save image bitmap to save into SD card

```
public static Uri saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

    File imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/screenshot.png");
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    Uri parse = Uri.parse(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/screenshot.png").toString());
    return parse;
}
```

**note**-Add permission in manifest:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
```

enjoy your code time:)

Comment: not work, this is the error Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)