# fileInputStream(file) gives open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) error

Tags: java, android, video, uri, fileinputstream

I am trying to upload a video on server. This is how i get the video

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
  intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
  intent.setType("video/*");
  startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_VIDEO);
```

i get the file uri this way

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
```

this is what i recieve

> content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A165191

i show the video preview this way

```
mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
 mVideoView.requestFocus();
 mVideoView.start();
```

Preview plays perfectly. then i need to make a file to upload it to server . i make this file this way

```
file = new File(uri.getPath());
```

but when i reach the line below, it gives error

```
 FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
```

i also tried uri.toString(); but still error. The error i recieve is below:

> 2 error: /document/video:165191: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or
>   directory)
>                                                          java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/video:165191: open failed:
>   ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Please someone help me ... it is really making me frustrated ..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620641/android-error-open-failed-enoent

Comment: Not every url can be represented as a file, call `url.openConnection().getInputStream()`

Answer (score 0):

The data URI that you get does not need to be a path on the file system - some apps implement it as a path, others as a unique URI which exposes their data through `ContentResolver`.

Your best bet would be to call [`openInputStream(uri)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openInputStream(android.net.Uri)), which returns an InputStream. Depending on your implementation of the server upload, you can either use that to stream bytes to the server directly, or pass the bytes to a `FileOutputStream`, save the data to a file and use that for your upload.