# Android Studio App crashes when I'm starting it on handy without debugger

Tags: android, google-maps, debugging

Since yesterday my app hangs when I start it without the debugger. When I debug the app everything works fine. I don't know if I should post the code I think it's too much. 
I'm using the Google Maps API.

### **Logcat(Error):**

> 10-03 09:53:12.172 666-680/? E/Sensors: poll() failed (Interrupted
>   system call) 10-03 09:53:15.802 666-680/? E/Sensors: poll() failed
>   (Interrupted system call) 10-03 09:53:17.128
>   18439-18520/com.example.luick.boat_rc E/dalvikvm: Fatal
>   spin-on-suspend, dumping threads 10-03 09:53:17.250
>   18439-18520/com.example.luick.boat_rc E/dalvikvm: threadid=31: stuck
>   on threadid=11, giving up 10-03 09:53:17.566 666-687/? E/ANRManager:
>   ANR in com.example.luick.boat_rc
>   (com.example.luick.boat_rc/.MainActivity)
>                                              Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting because the touched window has not finished
>   processing the input events that were previously delivered to it.)
>                                              Load: 10.36 / 10.26 / 10.14
>                                              Android time :[2016-10-03 09:53:17.565] [167215,125]
>                                              CPU usage from 0ms to 6136ms later:
>                                                97% 18439/com.example.luick.boat_rc: 95% user + 1.6% kernel / faults: 277
>   minor
>                                                23% 666/system_server: 18% user + 5% kernel / faults: 437 minor
>                                                5.7% 163/adbd: 0.4% user + 5.2% kernel / faults: 569 minor
>                                                3.4% 12471/logcat: 1.7% user + 1.6% kernel
>                                                1.7% 934/com.android.phone: 0.9% user + 0.8% kernel / faults: 153 minor
>                                                1.4% 741/com.android.systemui: 1.1% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 112 minor
>                                                0.8% 18117/kworker/0:1: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
>                                                0% 948/com.mediatek.voicecommand: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 252 minor
>   6 major
>                                                0% 963/com.mediatek.bluetooth: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 175 minor
>                                                0% 974/com.tinno.gesture.phone: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 240 minor
>                                                0.3% 18437/kworker/1:1: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
>                                                0% 2/kthreadd: 0% user + 0% kernel
>                                                0% 63/mmcqd/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
>                                                0.1% 68/disp_config_upd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
>                                                0% 125/debuggerd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 75 minor
>                                                0.1% 132/surfaceflinger: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
>                                                0% 845/tx_thread: 0% user + 0% kernel
>                                                0% 916/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 0% user + 0% kernel
>                                                0.1% 12991/kworker/u:0: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
>                                               +0% 18843/migration/2: 0% user + 0% kernel
>                                               +0% 18847/kworker/2:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
>                                               +0% 18848/ksoftirqd/2: 0% user + 0% kernel
>                                               +0% 18849/kworker/2:1: 0% user + 0% kernel
>                                              51% TOTAL: 44% user + 7.1% kernel + 0% iowait
>
> ### **Logcat(Warn):**
>
> ```
>                                                         10-03 09:58:15.311 666-687/? E/ActivityManager: writeStringToFile error:
> ```
>
> /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/tracing_on java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/tracing_on: open failed: ENOENT (No such
>   file or directory) 10-03 09:58:15.312 666-687/? E/ActivityManager:
>   writeStringToFile error:
>   /sys/kernel/debug/binder/transaction_log_enable
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /sys/kernel/debug/binder/transaction_log_enable: open failed: ENOENT
>   (No such file or directory)
>
> 10-03 09:58:18.855 19017-19026/com.example.luick.boat_rc E/dalvikvm:
>   Fatal spin-on-suspend, dumping threads 10-03 09:58:18.960
>   19017-19026/com.example.luick.boat_rc E/dalvikvm: threadid=4: stuck on
>   threadid=11, giving up
>
> 10-03 09:58:22.018 666-687/? E/ANRManager: ANR in
>   com.example.luick.boat_rc (com.example.luick.boat_rc/.MainActivity)
>                                              Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting because the touched window has not finished
>   processing the input events that were previously delivered to it.)
>                                              Load: 9.41 / 9.62 / 9.89
>                                              Android time :[2016-10-03 09:58:22.16] [167519,562]
>                                              CPU usage from 2080ms to -6692ms ago:
>                                                97% 19017/com.example.luick.boat_rc: 96% user + 1.1% kernel / faults: 319
>   minor
>                                                17% 666/system_server: 13% user + 3.4% kernel / faults: 729 minor
>                                                4.9% 163/adbd: 0.5% user + 4.3% kernel / faults: 773 minor
>                                                3.6% 12471/logcat: 1.5% user + 2% kernel
>                                                1.2% 741/com.android.systemui: 0.9% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 29 minor
>                                                1.2% 934/com.android.phone: 0.7% user + 0.4% kernel / faults: 2 minor
>                                                0.5% 18117/kworker/0:1: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
>                                                0.4% 132/surfaceflinger: 0.3% user + 0.1% kernel
>                                                0% 974/com.tinno.gesture.phone: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
>                                                0.3% 19015/kworker/1:1: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
>                                                0.1% 948/com.mediatek.voicecommand: 0.1% user + 0% kernel
>                                                0.1% 963/com.mediatek.bluetooth: 0% user + 0% kernel
>                                                0.2% 19011/kworker/0:0: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
>                                                0% 6/migration/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
>                                                0% 56/bat_thread_kthr: 0% user + 0% kernel
>                                                0% 63/mmcqd/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
>                                                0.1% 68/disp_config_upd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
>                                                0% 162/em_svr: 0% user + 0% kernel
>                                                0.1% 19174/kworker/u:2: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
>                                               +0% 19295/migration/2: 0% user + 0% kernel
>                                               +0% 19296/kworker/2:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
>                                               +0% 19297/ksoftirqd/2: 0% user + 0% kernel
>                                               +0% 19298/kworker/2:1: 0% user + 0% kernel
>                                              51% TOTAL: 45% user + 6.3% kernel 10-03 09:58:22.020 666-687/? E/ActivityManager: get crashInfo
>   fail.

### **Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyAL11W__n26lMvJ9y1Ea1jkvBR19REhE_g" />
</application>
```

### **MainActivity:**

```
   package com.example.luick.boat_rc;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;

import com.example.luick.boat_rc.de.ye.boat_conCONTROL.GPSTracker;

import android.location.Location;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.format.Formatter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.luick.boat_rc.de.ye.boat_conCONTROL.CONNECT;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener, OnMapReadyCallback {


    public static GoogleMap mMap;
    public static String RASP_IP = "192.168.42.1";
    public static boolean STATUS = false;
    public static SensorManager sensorManager;
    public static boolean KIPP = false;
    public static Switch S_K;
    public static ImageButton B_RELOAD;
    public static String MODE;
    public static ImageButton uf;
    public static ImageButton f;
    public static ImageButton s;
    public static ImageButton ra;
    public static Switch is;
    public static Switch tr;
    public static ImageView wifi_warn;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    SupportMapFragment sMapF;
    GPSTracker gps;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sMapF = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        B_RELOAD = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.B_RELOAD);
        //i2.setEnabled(false);
        uf = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.uf);
        f = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.f);
        s = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.s);
        ra = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.r);
        s.setImageResource(R.drawable.up);
        f.setImageResource(R.drawable.upg2);
        uf.setImageResource(R.drawable.upg3);
        is = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.S_IS);
        tr = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.S_TR);
        wifi_warn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wifi_warn);
        wifi_warn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Thread si = new Thread(new MainActivity.SEND_IP());
        si.start();
        is.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if (isChecked) {
                    CONNECT.writer_sens_front.println("ON");
                    CONNECT.writer_sens_front.flush();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inelligent_ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    CONNECT.writer_sens_front.println("OFF");
                    CONNECT.writer_sens_front.flush();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inelligent_OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
        tr.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if (isChecked) {
                    CONNECT.writer_track.println("ON");
                    CONNECT.writer_track.flush();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TRACKING....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    CONNECT.writer_track.println("OFF");
                    CONNECT.writer_track.flush();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TRACKING_OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
        ra.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    KIPP = true;
                    ra.setImageResource(R.drawable.ar);

                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    KIPP = false;
                    ra.setImageResource(R.drawable.dr);
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager sFm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        sFm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.map, sMapF).commit();
        sMapF.getMapAsync(this);
        //gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
       //Thread CAR_MAP_OBJECT = new Thread(new MainActivity.CAR_MAP_OBJECT());
        //CAR_MAP_OBJECT.start();

        //Thread USER_MAP_OBJECT = new Thread(new MainActivity.USER_MAP_OBJECT());
        //USER_MAP_OBJECT.start();
    }


    public void WIFI() {
        Context context = MainActivity.this;
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        int numberOfLevels = 5;
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        int level = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(wifiInfo.getRssi(), numberOfLevels);
        if (Math.round(level) < 2) {
            wifi_warn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            wifi_warn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void B_RELOAD(View v) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new CONNECT());
        t.start();
    }

    public void s(View v) {
        MODE = "s";
        s.setImageResource(R.drawable.up);
        f.setImageResource(R.drawable.upg2);
        uf.setImageResource(R.drawable.upg3);
        if (STATUS == true) {
            CONNECT.writer_modi.println("s");
            CONNECT.writer_modi.flush();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SLOW", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void f(View v) {
        MODE = "f";
        s.setImageResource(R.drawable.upg);
        f.setImageResource(R.drawable.up2);
        uf.setImageResource(R.drawable.upg3);
        if (STATUS == true) {
            CONNECT.writer_modi.println("f");
            CONNECT.writer_modi.flush();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FAST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void uf(View v) {
        MODE = "uf";
        s.setImageResource(R.drawable.upg);
        f.setImageResource(R.drawable.upg2);
        uf.setImageResource(R.drawable.up3);
        if (STATUS == true) {
            CONNECT.writer_modi.println("uf");
            CONNECT.writer_modi.flush();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ULTRA_FAST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {


        WIFI();
        if (KIPP == true) {
            float output = ((event.values[1] - 1) * (500 - 1)) / (20 - 1) + 1;
            //output= ((input-minInput) * (maxOutput-minOutput)) / (maxInput-minInput) + minOutput;
            float output_eng = ((event.values[2] - 1) * (500 - 1)) / (20 - 1) + 1;
            //output= ((input-minInput) * (maxOutput-minOutput)) / (maxInput-minInput) + minOutput;

            int send = Math.round(output);

            int send_eng = Math.round(output_eng);

            if (STATUS == true) {
                //     if (send < 100 && send > -100) {
                //      CONNECT.writer_dir.println("15");
                //      CONNECT.writer_dir.flush();
                //  } else if (send > 100) {
                //      CONNECT.writer_dir.println("21");
                //      CONNECT.writer_dir.flush();

                //  } else if (send < -100) {
                //      CONNECT.writer_dir.println("10");
                //      CONNECT.writer_dir.flush();

                //Lenken
                if (MODE == "s" || MODE == null) {
                    if (send < 100 && send > -100) {
                        CONNECT.writer_dir.println("middle");
                        CONNECT.writer_dir.flush();
                    } else {
                        if (send > 100) {
                            CONNECT.writer_dir.println("right");
                            CONNECT.writer_dir.flush();
                        } else {
                            if (send < -100) {
                                CONNECT.writer_dir.println("left");
                                CONNECT.writer_dir.flush();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (MODE == "f") {
                    if (send < 100 && send > -100) {
                        CONNECT.writer_dir.println("middle");
                        CONNECT.writer_dir.flush();
                    } else {
                        if (send > 100) {
                            CONNECT.writer_dir.println("right");
                            CONNECT.writer_dir.flush();
                        } else {
                            if (send < -100) {
                                CONNECT.writer_dir.println("left");
                                CONNECT.writer_dir.flush();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (MODE == "uf") {
                    if (send < 100 && send > -100) {
                        CONNECT.writer_dir.println("middle");
                        CONNECT.writer_dir.flush();
                    } else {
                        if (send > 100) {
                            CONNECT.writer_dir.println("right");
                            CONNECT.writer_dir.flush();
                        } else {
                            if (send < -100) {
                                CONNECT.writer_dir.println("left");
                                CONNECT.writer_dir.flush();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                //Lenken


                //Motor
                if (MODE == "s" || MODE == null) {

                    if (send_eng < 75 && send_eng > -75) {
                        CONNECT.writer_eng.println("0");
                        CONNECT.writer_eng.flush();
                    } else {
                        if (send_eng < -75) {
                            CONNECT.writer_eng.println("B");
                            CONNECT.writer_eng.println("150");
                            CONNECT.writer_eng.flush();
                        } else if (send_eng > 75) {
                            CONNECT.writer_eng.println("F");
                            CONNECT.writer_eng.println("150");
                            CONNECT.writer_eng.flush();

                        }
                    }
                } else if (MODE == "f") {

                    if (send_eng < 75 && send_eng > -75) {
                        CONNECT.writer_eng.println("0");
                        CONNECT.writer_eng.flush();
                    } else {
                        if (send_eng < -75) {
                            CONNECT.writer_eng.println("B");
                            CONNECT.writer_eng.println("150");
                            CONNECT.writer_eng.flush();
                        } else if (send_eng > 75) {
                            CONNECT.writer_eng.println("F");
                            CONNECT.writer_eng.println("180");
                            CONNECT.writer_eng.flush();

                        }
                    }

                } else if (MODE == "uf") {

                    if (send_eng < 75 && send_eng > -75) {
                        CONNECT.writer_eng.println("0");
                        CONNECT.writer_eng.flush();
                    } else {
                        if (send_eng < -75) {
                            CONNECT.writer_eng.println("B");
                            CONNECT.writer_eng.println("0");
                            CONNECT.writer_eng.flush();
                        } else if (send_eng > 75) {
                            CONNECT.writer_eng.println("F");
                            CONNECT.writer_eng.println("199");
                            CONNECT.writer_eng.flush();

                        }
                    }
                }

                //Motor
            }
        } else {
            if (STATUS == true) {
                CONNECT.writer_eng.println("0");
                CONNECT.writer_eng.flush();
                CONNECT.writer_dir.println("middle");
                CONNECT.writer_dir.flush();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // register this class as a listener for the orientation and
        // accelerometer sensors
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    public class SEND_IP implements Runnable {


        @Override
        public void run() {
            while ((true)) {
                if (STATUS == true) {
                    WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
                    String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
                    CONNECT.writer_con.println(ip);
                    CONNECT.writer_con.flush();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap=googleMap;
    }
/*
    public class CAR_MAP_OBJECT implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run(){
            try {Thread.sleep(10000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            while (true){
                try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                MainActivity.mMap.clear();

                MarkerOptions car = new MarkerOptions();
                LatLng car_O = new LatLng(49.466786666666674,10.967413333333311);

                car.position(car_O);

                car.title("CAR");

                MainActivity.mMap.addMarker(car);

                MainActivity.mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(car_O, 16));
                //49.466786666666664
                //Longitude 10.967413333333331
            }
        }

    }*/

  /*  public class USER_MAP_OBJECT implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run(){
            try {Thread.sleep(2000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            while (true){
                try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                if(gps.canGetLocation()){
                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                    Log.v(TAG,"Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude);
                    //Location location = gps.getLocation();

                    //mMap.clear();

                    //MarkerOptions user = new MarkerOptions();

                    //user.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));

                    //user.title("You");

                    //mMap.addMarker(user);

                    //mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    //      new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 16));
                }else{
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }
            }
        }

    }*/
}
```

The Java Code is just the MainActivity there are a few other classes but i think the error is in MainActivity and caused by Google Maps.

Thanks to pcpriyanka for editing :D

Comment: Try to check this [Github](https://github.com/marcshilling/react-native-image-picker/issues/72) and [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620641/android-error-open-failed-enoent) if it can help you. Just try to follow the different provided solutions. Also, make sure that you use Android studio for this project, and try to clean or rebuild the project itself.

Answer (score 0):

Add these permissions to manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and you are good to go..

Comment: which file are you trying to access?

Comment: I dont understand your answer.. I not want to access any file :}

Comment: can you show me where exactly you are getting this error? post your java code

Comment: I dont know where i am getting the error that s the problem!